# Display distinct record for each employee

Tags: mysql, distinct

I have two tables appointment app and faculty fac. they are multiple record with same emp ids

1. I need to join two tables by `app.employeeid=fac.empid` (here i will get duplicate records)
2. and `app.begindate<=now and app.enddate>=now and app.percent>.50` (here also i will get duplicate records because empid(multiple records with same id) can have same begindate,end date and >.50 )
3. `max(app.amt)` (here also i will get duplicate records because there can be a chance where empid(multiple records with same id) have same amt) . Finally at the end i want to select distinct(max(app.amt)) to get only single record for empid.

I used the query:

```
select max(app.amt) ,fac.email,fac.employee_id,fac.empid,fac.first_name,fac.last_name,fac.department_id,fac.titlecode,app.begindate,app.enddate,app.percent,
app.title_name,app.department_name from faculty fac, appointment app where 
app.employeeid=fac.empid and app.begindate <= now() and app.enddate >= now() and app.percent>.50  group by fac.empid
/
```

i am having an issue i am getting max(app.amt) but corresponding column values are not properly matched with max amt record.the other column values are taking in random.I want the exact corresponding values to display.

sample date in appointment table for few fileds:

```
SELECT app.amt, fac.email, fac.employee_id, fac.empid, 
                 fac.first_name, fac.last_name, fac.department_id, fac.titlecode,
                 app.begindate, app.enddate, app.percent,
                 app.title_name, app.department_name 
FROM appointment app
LEFT JOIN appointment app2                                    -- self-join to locate  max
ON app.employee_id = app2.employee_id AND app.amt < app2.amt --  of app.amt
INNER JOIN faculty fac ON app.employee_id=fac.empid           -- join to fac
WHERE app2.amt IS NULL                                        -- isolate rows with     max(app.amt)
AND app.begindate <= NOW() 
AND app.enddate >= NOW() 
AND app.percent>.50 group by fac.empid


employee_id begindate enddate     amt        percent  department_name
5528        7/1/2011  9/30/2011   0          1        m1
5528        7/1/2011  9/30/2011   193100     1        m1
5528        10/1/2011 6/30/2013   79000      1        m1
5528        10/1/2011 6/30/2013   118500     1        m2
5528        10/1/2011 6/30/2013   0          1        m2
```

Answer (score 1):

To select not only a MAX(column) but the row corresponding to it, for each employee_id, you usually use a LEFT JOIN to join the table to itself. (This is also known as "greatest-n-per-group" and there are a number of questions in this vein on stackoverflow under this tag).

e.g. to select the `max(app.amt`) per `employee_id` *with its corresponding row* you would do:

```
SELECT app.*
FROM appointment app
LEFT JOIN appointment app2
 ON app.employee_id = app2.employee_id AND app.amt < app2.amt
WHERE app2.amt IS NULL;
```

Why does this work? In essence, this says "pick the row with the `amt` for which there is no higher `amt` for that employee", for each employee.

The `LEFT JOIN appointment app2 ON app.employee_id=app2.employee_id` joins `app` to itself on the `employee_id` (note this is what you wanted to `GROUP BY`). This produces a table of `appointment` with every possible pair of `amt` for each `employee_id`.

Then, we also specify that `app.amt < app2.amt`. So we only display rows where the `(app.amt,app2.amt)` pair has the former less than the latter.
Since this is a `LEFT JOIN`, if we happen to find an `app.amt` for which we can't find a corresponding row in `app2` with the same employee_id and a *greater* `app2.amt`, then `app2.amt` is set to NULL. This occurs *precisely* when we've found the *greatest* `app.amt` for that employee.

### Solution

So, adapt your query using this "`LEFT JOIN` to myself to get the corresponding row" method:

```
SELECT app.amt, fac.email, fac.employee_id, fac.empid, 
                     fac.first_name, fac.last_name, fac.department_id, fac.titlecode,
                     app.begindate, app.enddate, app.percent,
                     app.title_name, app.department_name 
FROM appointment app
LEFT JOIN appointment app2                                    -- self-join to locate max
 ON app.employee_id = app2.employee_id AND app.amt < app2.amt --  of app.amt
INNER JOIN faculty fac ON app.employee_id=fac.empid           -- join to fac
WHERE app2.amt IS NULL                                        -- isolate rows with max(app.amt)
  AND app.begindate <= NOW() 
  AND app.enddate >= NOW() 
  AND app.percent>.50
```

So, the only things that have changed are:

- added a `LEFT JOIN appointment app2 ... WHERE app2.amt IS NULL` to locate the row with the max `app.amt` for each `employeeid`.
- changed your `FROM app, fac .. WHERE app.employeeid=fac.empid` into a `JOIN` (see note below)
- no need for the `GROUP BY` or `MAX(app.amt)` -- the `INNER JOIN` takes care of that.

Note on converting the `FROM app, fac ... WHERE join_condition` to `FROM app LEFT JOIN fac ON join_condition`: a join tends to be more efficient than selecting from multiple tables and joining in the `WHERE`.

What type of join you use (`app` to `fac`) may make a difference to your results; to recover your former behaviour use `INNER JOIN`. This will only display rows where the employee exists in *both* the `app` table *and* the `fac` table.

Using a `LEFT JOIN` is slightly more efficient than the `INNER JOIN`, and the results will be identical *unless* there is an employee in your appointments table who does not have an entry in the faculty table. Then they will be displayed in the results list with `NULL` for all the `fac.xxx` fields.

Using a `RIGHT JOIN` will show every employee from the faculty table regardless of whether they have appointments or not -- if they have no appointments they'll still be shown in your results, just with `NULL` for all their appointment-related fields.

Just subtle differences in the JOINs (ahh, but that's another question).

Comment: I am getting duplicate records because i can have same max amt multiple times..for the above query all the max amt records are coming but if i have same max amt recors for one empid at that i want distinct max amt record

Comment: I want the query based on the order first join condition nxt begindate,end date,percent and than max amt record ..still they can be multiple records with same max amt for one employee..so i want distinct of max amt. Suppose first if i can get max amt record they will be a problem it can eliminate the records less than begindate and grter than end date.so i want the order specified according to my requirement.plz help me out...

Comment: If you have one employee with the same max amt multiple times, how do you want to choose which on to pick (e.g. use some sort of primary key)? The records with begindate <= now and enddate >= now are already eliminated. To specify the order you add a `ORDER BY ` and your fields to the query.

Comment: If i use groupby empid at the end of the query i am getting a single record but what i want is first get the list of records based on joincond,begindate,end date and then from the list returned get the max amt record.but the query you specified will first get the max amt rec  and thn begindate and enddate.if this is the case i am missing some records according to my requirement.

Comment: The order doesn't matter here -- you will get everything that satisfies the join condition and your begin date constraint, and your end date constraint, and with the max amt.  The question is how to determine which row to return when there are duplicate max amts. GROUP BY could work.

Comment: example data in appoinment table:

Comment: added sample appoinment table data in question.5528        10/1/2011 6/30/2013   118500     1 .that record should be displayed according to my requirement.but it is not displayed may be this query is checking for dates first and eliminationg..please help me out