# subquery to eliminate duplicate record

Tags: mysql

There will be multiple records in both tables with same emp id
I need to query

1. join condition app.employee_id=fac.empid
2. app.begindate,app,enddate,app.percent
3. max(amt) but still i can have a chance of duplicate record because for an employee the amt can be same so i need distinct of max amt record.

But my below query will get the max record first and then query begindate date,end date and percent

I want to query in the order i specified above.

```
SELECT app.amt, fac.email, fac.employee_id, fac.empid, 
                     fac.first_name, fac.last_name, fac.department_id, fac.titlecode,
                     app.begindate, app.enddate, app.percent,
                     app.title_name, app.department_name 
FROM appointment app
LEFT JOIN appointment app2                                    -- self-join to locate max
 ON app.employee_id = app2.employee_id AND app.amt < app2.amt --  of app.amt
INNER JOIN faculty fac ON app.employee_id=fac.empid            -- join to fac
WHERE app2.amt IS NULL                                        -- isolate rows with max(app.amt)
  AND app.begindate <= NOW() 
  AND app.enddate >= NOW() 
  AND app.percent>.50 group by empid
```

Comment: Are employeeid and employee_id for appointment table different columns or just a typo?

Comment: Your query seems to return nothing for employees with max amt in a row not satisfying date or percent requirement, is that expected? Can you write more about what are you trying to achieve with some example data maybe?

Comment: my above query will get the unique records for the employee based on max amt,join condition,begindate,enddate and percent.But i need to query the order specified above like first join two tables with their id than sort based on condition begindate,end date and percent and then max amt record.

Comment: Follow on from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8980972/display-distinct-record-for-each-employee/8981128#8981128)  which might provide more context